# Highlight days with events on solspace calendar

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

I am using your the solspace calendar extension. I need to be able to highlight by adding a class to the td

I googled the request and I came across a few results but your archived  forum seems to be not working any more

Is there a tag I can use  {if event has results} etc

Thanks

{display_each_day}
 {day format="%j"} 
 {/display_each_day}

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `{exp:calendar:cal}` tag, within `{display_each_day} ... {/display_each_day}` you can use a `{day_event_count}` (http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/calendar/#day_event_count) in a conditional:

```
{display_each_day}
   <td class="{if day_event_count > 0}HIGHLIGHT CLASS{/if}">
      {day format="%j"}
   </td>
{/display_each_day}
```

Alternatively, `{event_count}` can also be used in some cases: http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/calendar/#event_count

Comment: neither of those tags render        {display_each_day}
                              {if day_in_current_month}
                                 <td class="day_cell">{day_event_count}{event_count}<

Comment: I used js and i got it to work       $('td .event').closest('td').addClass('has_event');

Comment: Have you tried the `{day_event_count}` and `{event_count}` variables _outside_ of the `{if day_in_current_month}...{/if}` conditional? JS is another workaround as well I guess.